# How to locally cache audio when streaming with Sound.load() in Adobe AIR?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air

I'm building a mobile MP3 player with AIR, which streams audio using the Sound class's .load() function. I'd like to cache this audio **as** it's downloaded, to the the user's SD card.

Is this possible without having to download the file twice??

Answer (score 0):

Sound class has [extract()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#extract%28%29) method which fills ByteArray with raw sound data. Note that this will be uncompressed samples taking up lot of space.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I ended up opting for background downloading with URLStream, and only using Sound.load() to kick off the first song.

Thinking that I could download, decompress, playback and write to file at the same time was probably a bit ambitious!!